# Visual studio refactoring - move class to assembly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, class, refactoring, rename

I'm looking for the simplest (and most complete) mechanism to move a class from one to another assembly with reference (dependency) fixing capability.I know some manual ways to do that like :
 - use built-in move rename, then cutpaste, multiple save ... 
 - use resharper rename namespace, cutpaste , the same as above

but with the problem is the same with those : in a web environment (namely ASP.Net) almost all of the references (for user controls for example, let's suppose with assembly name in their path for a virtual path provider scenario) are coded a string references (not to mention the configuration files and other external reference sources) - unfortunately even resharper doesn't found all. Other problem is with the designer files - you know they're generated on at least save action accordingly to the specifications in control and sometimes they're somehow mixed with the rename action I mean here's the old there's the new assembly name etc.

Thanks in advance,
  Nicolai

Comment: have you tried refactor from devexpress? They also have a free version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Resharper try the [Test Driven Development](http://code.google.com/p/resharper-tdd-productivity-plugin/)

It Allows a number of refactors like that.